# Count the number of occurrences in a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that outputs a list of rows with your standard basic `SELECT` statement using a few `joins` and `where` clauses.

```
Employee        Value
--------------------------
Tommy Elliott   Damage
Tommy Elliott   Overage
Tommy Elliott   Damage
Tommy Elliott   Shortage
Tommy Elliott   Damage
Tommy Elliott   Shortage
Trevor Gray     Overage
Trevor Gray     Shortage
Trevor Gray     Overage
Trevor Gray     Shortage
Trevor Gray     Overage
Trevor Gray     Shortage
```

I am wondering if anyone would know of a solution where I can either add a new SELECT statement below this one or within the same SELECT statement that would be able to:

- count the number of times Tommy and Trevor appear (which should be six based on the data above)
- and for Tommy and Trevor, count the number of times they have a value of damage, overage, or shortage.

I've been trying to figure it out and can't. I'm sure there's a quick solution to `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analytic version of `COUNT()` can add these as column values *and* preserve the detail you want. Assuming your query starts like this:

```
SELECT
  Employee,
  Value
FROM ... and the rest of your query
```

... add the counts like this:

```
SELECT
  Employee,
  Value,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee) AS ThisEmpCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = 'Damage' THEN 1 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY Employee) AS ThisEmpDamageCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = 'Outage' THEN 1 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY Employee) AS ThisEmpOutageCount
FROM ... and the rest of your query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T.Employee, COUNT(T.Employee)
from 
(
  your query
)T
group by T.Employee
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Employee, Value, Count(1) as No_Of_Times
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Employee, Value
ORDER BY Employee, Value
```